# How to set RunPath of a binary?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

There are countless threads describing what is `RPATH`, `RUNPATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and how they interact in order to resolve libraries' location.

To set `RPATH` use gcc options:

```
-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/dir
```

To set LD_LIBRARY_PATH use:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH= <path of lib>
```

What I cannot find is how to set `RUNPATH`?

Answer (score 9):

Seems runpath is set to the -Wl value if you pass --enable-new-dtags

http://blog.tremily.us/posts/rpath/

This links seems to suggest the difference in use for rpath and runpath seems to be their order in the search list:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath