# How to set RPATH and RUNPATH with GCC/LD?

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, ld, dynamic-linking

I recently encountered this problem after an upgrade of the system: using the GCC `-Wl,-rpath=` option works differently than before.

I used it to set the search paths to some shared libraries that were built in a sub-module of my project. At the time I considered it better than setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` system-wide (I didn't want to set it every time I turned on the computer). Everything worked fine, and these two approaches seemed equivalent.

Now it seems that the behavior of `-rpath` has changed. It still works for directly dependent libraries, but not for those that link other libraries from the same directory set via `-rpath=`. Exporting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` still works as before.

I inspected the output of the compilation using `readelf` and there is a difference. Before upgrade (Linux Mint 18.2 with GCC 5.4) the *Dynamic section* had this line:

```
0x000000000000000f (RPATH)            Library rpath: [submod/lib]
```

After the upgrade (Linux Mint 19 with GCC 7.3) the line changed to:

```
0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [submod/lib]
```

In [use RPATH but not RUNPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967848/use-rpath-but-not-runpath) it is suggested that RPATH was replaced by RUNPATH (or that it at least servers a different purpose as it has a lower priority), but it doesn't give an answer as to why this effects indirect linking. The libraries themselves have neither RPATH, or RUNPATH in `readelf` output.

So my question is this: **Why has the linker suddenly started to interpret the `-rpath=` option differently, and is there a way to force the old behavior?** (Or do something different that will yield an equivalent result.)

Another question would be: **Is it possible to tell the old version of linker to produce the new output (i.e. RUNPATH instead of RPATH)?**

---

**EDIT**

This is not a duplicate of [How to set RunPath of a binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943102/how-to-set-runpath-of-a-binary) -- my question is the opposite: I want the behavior of RPATH. I figured it out (thanks to the tip in the comment), and I will answer my questions here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set RunPath of a binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26943102/608639), [Use RPATH but not RUNPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7967848/608639), etc. I believe the new way to do things is `-Wl,-rpath,<path>` and `-Wl,--enable-new-dtags`. It allows you to override the embedded paths with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and it is what the Coreutil folks recommend for binaries.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Is there a way to force the old behavior?

Yes. You can use this option `-Wl,--disable-new-dtags` to tell the *new* linker to use the *old* behavior, i.e. RPATH.

> Is it possible to tell the old version of linker to produce the new output (i.e. RUNPATH instead of RPATH)?

Yes. Use `-Wl,--enable-new-dtags` to tell the *old* linker to use the *new* behavior, i.e. RUNPATH.

I verified the executable with `readelf` and these two options seem to control what will be written in the ELF Dynamic section. I think the problem was caused by a change in the defaults for the new version, although, interestingly, the manual page for `ld` would suggest that it should still be the same:

> --enable-new-dtags
>   --disable-new-dtags
>                  This linker can create the new dynamic tags in ELF. But the older ELF systems may not understand them. If you specify
>   --enable-new-dtags, the new dynamic tags will be created as needed and
>                  older dynamic tags will be omitted.  If you specify --disable-new-dtags, no new dynamic tags will be created. **By default, the new dynamic tags are not created.** Note that those options are
>                  only available for ELF systems.

Answer (score 15):

The project GNU Binutils  (containing GNU linker (ld)) is not at the origin of this change of behaviour, but Debian (2016)[1](https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/b/binutils/binutils_2.28-5_changelog), and Gentoo (2013!)[2](http://marc.info/?l=gentoo-commits&m=150605095716254&w=2).

According to gentoo commit from Mike Frysinger on  Jan 2013 :

> "The "new" dtags options have been around for 14+ years now, so for
>   Linux and GNU targets, enable them by default."

This change are not well received [3](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=847298), [4](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=859732), [5](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/1253638), as RUNPATH and RPATH  have "undocumented behaviour difference"... 
Surprisingly this changes is now applied on Debian stable.

The problem is that using RUNPATH, leads to unpredictable problems...
But mainly just works . From wikipedia :

> The ld dynamic linker does not search DT_RUNPATH locations for
>   **transitive dependencies**, unlike DT_RPATH.