# Why would runpath be ignored?

Tags: shared-libraries, ld, rpath

On CentOS 7.2, I've built an app with g++ 4.8.5 that can't run because it can't find a library that **does** exist in its `runpath`. I'm pretty sure it worked two weeks ago. What could cause this?

```
$ ./app
./app: error while loading shared libraries: libhdf5.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ ldd ./app | grep libhdf5
    libhdf5.so.9 => not found

$ readelf app -d | grep path
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/opt/ProductName/lib:/opt/ProductName/lib/private]

$ ll /opt/ProductName/lib/libhdf5.so*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 fotechd fotechd      16 Oct 26 14:38 /opt/ProductName/lib/libhdf5.so -> libhdf5.so.9.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 fotechd fotechd      16 Oct 26 14:38 /opt/ProductName/lib/libhdf5.so.9 -> libhdf5.so.9.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 fotechd fotechd 3316074 Oct 26 14:35 /opt/ProductName/lib/libhdf5.so.9.0.0
```

Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` fixes it temporarily:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ProductName/lib ./app
...
OK
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on a fedora 29 system. Have you been able to solve it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have been able to solve this issue on my side. For me it was because the not found library was an indirect one and `runpath` actually does not resolve indirect dependencies. I fixed it with using `rpath` instead of `runpath` by passing the additional `-Wl,--disable-new-dtags` linker option to the compiler.

There is a good and detailed explanation here: [How to set RPATH and RUNPATH with GCC/LD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018092/how-to-set-rpath-and-runpath-with-gcc-ld)

Comment: So you're saying that if your app loads an .so, which loads another .so, the second .so is unaffected by the runpath (but is affected by rpath)?

Comment: In my case I couldn't tell which dependencies are indirect since `ldd` only shows a flat list (and I'm new to the codebase). To get a proper tree structure you need to call `lddtree` instead, which is part of `pax-utils` (on CentOS I got it with `sudo yum install pax-utils --enablerepo=epel`).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what an indirect dependency is: "a .so loaded by a .so". In my case, the not found .so was not in the list of (NEEDED) libraries you get with `readelf -d`

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the shared objects, dlopen() searches the following, in this order:

- the runtime library search path that was set using the -rpath option to ld (see the Utilities Reference) when the binary was linked
- directories specified by the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable
- directories specified by the _CS_LIBPATH configuration string

It seems `dlopen()` does not check on `RUNPATH`.

http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0SP1.update/com.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref/d/dlopen.html