# Managing secondary dependencies of shared libraries

Tags: shared-libraries, dependency-management, dynamic-linking

I have a problem with the seconday dependences of the shared libraries.
Suppose we have the following dependency tree:

```
libA.so
├─libB.so
└─libC.so
  └─libD.so
```

That is, a shared library A depends on shared libraries B and C, and shared library C depends itself on shared library D. A good example for `libC` is [GSL shared library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl) which depends on CBLAS.

To make a self-sufficient easy-to-use package and to avoid problems with different versions of installed shared libraries, I package the libraries `libB`, `libC` and `libD` with `libA`, and as explained, e.g., in Drepper’s [article](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), “How to write shared libraries” (2011), I add the link flag `-Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN --enable-new-dtags` to set the `RUN_PATH` of `libA.so`, so that the dynamic loader can find the dependencies of `libA` in the corresponding directories, without needing to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (which has its downsides).

The problem is that setting the `RUN_PATH` in `libA` does not help with the secondary dependencies, like `libD.so`.
Turning on the dynamic loader debug messages (via setting `LD_DEBUG`) reveals that the loader attempts to find `libD.so` only in the *standard* library locations, and not in the location of `libA` (contrary to what it does for finding `libB` or `libC`).

Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Indeed, I can link the libraries C and D statically, if I have the source code or properly compiled static libraries.
But is there a better way?

---

**Solution**:
As explained by `Employed Russian` the solution is to set `RPATH` instead of `RUNPATH`.
With recent versions of GCC, one should use the following link flag:

```
-Wl,--disable-new-dtags,-rpath,\$ORIGIN
```

`RPATH` is searched for *transitive* dependencies; that is, paths in `RPATH` will be considered for everything that is dynamically loaded, even dependencies of dependencies.

In contrast, the `ld` dynamic linker does *not* search `RUNPATH` locations for transitive dependencies (unlike `RPATH`).

See also:

- Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath#The_role_of_GNU_ld
- SO question: [How to set RPATH and RUNPATH with GCC/LD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52018092)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By setting `DT_RUNPATH` you are telling the loader that *each* of your binaries is linked with all of its dependencies.

But that *isn't true* for `libC.so` -- it (apparently) doesn't have `DT_RUNPATH` of its own.

> I can link the libraries C and D statically, ... But is there a better way?

Yes: link `libC.so` with correct `DT_RUNPATH` (if `libC.so` and `libD.so` are in the same directory, then `-Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN` will work for `libC.so` as well).

**Update:**

> The problem is that I may not have the source or the properly compiled object files of `libC`

In that cause you should use `RPATH` instead of `RUNPATH`. Unlike the latter, the former applies to the object itself and to *all* dependencies of that object.

In other words, using `--enable-new-dtags` is wrong in this case -- you want the opposite.

> In this case, there is no solution (besides static linking); correct?

The other solution (besides using `RPATH`) is to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the environment.

**Update 2:**

> Difference between `RPATH` and `RUNPATH`

The difference is explained in the l[d.so man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html):

```
       If a shared object dependency does not contain a slash, then it
       is searched for in the following order:

       o  Using the directories specified in the DT_RPATH dynamic
          section attribute of the binary if present and DT_RUNPATH
          attribute does not exist.  Use of DT_RPATH is deprecated.
...
       o  Using the directories specified in the DT_RUNPATH dynamic
          section attribute of the binary if present.  Such directories
          are searched only to find those objects required by DT_NEEDED
          (direct dependencies) entries and do not apply to those
          objects' children, which must themselves have their own
          DT_RUNPATH entries.  This is unlike DT_RPATH, which is applied
          to searches for all children in the dependency tree.
```

Comment: So, the way you propose it to *recompile* `libC` with a correct `RUNPATH`; right?

Comment: @AlQuemist _Relink_ `libC`, yes.

Comment: The problem is that I may _not_ have the source or the properly compiled object files of `libC`. In this case, there is no solution (besides static linking); correct? @Employed Russian ?

Comment: @AlQuemist I've updated the answer.

Comment: Great! Could you also add some references for the points you mentioned?

Comment: I checked the proposed solution on `gcc 10.2.1`: One needs the link flag `-Wl,--disable-new-dtags,-rpath,\$ORIGIN` to set `RPATH` instead of `RUNPATH`. And that works! :)

Comment: @AlQuemist If the answer resolved your problem please accept (and upvote) it.

Comment: I have already upvoted your answer. Could you add some reference to the related documentation regarding the point about the difference between `RPATH` and `RUNPATH`?

Comment: @AlQuemist I've updated the answer.

Comment: Do you know if this difference between the behaviour of `RPATH` and `RUNPATH` (`RPATH` is transitive while `RUNPATH` is not) is a bug or intended?

Comment: @AlQuemist It is clearly intended. Otherwise there would be no difference between `RPATH` and `RUNPATH`, and no need to introduce `RUNPATH` in the first place.